# Assigning a new QStringList to the private QStringList of my QStringListModel

Tags: c++, qt, oop, model-view-controller

Sorry for the noob question. I went through the documentation and created a QStringListModel of my own. What I need to do is assign all the entries of a QStringList as the entries of my model (thus set the private member of my model equal to the new QStringList).

I created the model pretty much exactly as per the documentation so I won't list it here. I declare my model I use in the hpp file like this:

```
QAbstractItemModel *oldFilesModel;
```

Even though I create it in the cpp like this:

```
oldFilesModel = new FileListModel(emptyStringList);
```

Now, I have added a new public function in my derived class (FileListModel - which is derived from QStringListModel) like this:

in hpp:

```
void setStringList(QStringList newList);
```

in cpp:

```
void FileListModel::setStringList(QStringList newList)
{
    this->removeRows(0,this->rowCount());
    fileNames = newList;
}
```

This should set my private QStringList called fileNames equal to the QStringList newList correct?? (Not sure if this is the right way to do it, so any other advice will be much appreciated).

My problem is that I cannot call this function in my cpp files as my model is of type QAbstractItemModel. How can I access this function from my subclass if my object is defined as a type of the base class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear why you want to declare `oldFilesModel` as a `QAbstractItemModel` in the first place--why not declare it as a `QStringListModel`?  This would eliminate at least one aspect of your problem immediately.

But the larger issue is that you seem to be adding your own `QStringList` data member to `FileListModel`--but if it's derived from `QStringListModel`, then it already has this, along with the [setter](http://qt.developpez.com/doc/5.0-snapshot/qstringlistmodel/#setstringlist) and [getter](http://qt.developpez.com/doc/5.0-snapshot/qstringlistmodel/#stringlist) functions.

So working this out will require a little rewriting.  Specifically there is no need for your own version of these functions in `FileListModel`, or for `fileNames`--`QStringListModel` was created precisely to save you the trouble of writing these yourself.  But back to the first issue--if you have to cast, then do this:

```
qobject_cast<QStringListModel*>(oldFilesModel)->setStringList(newList);
```

Comment: So, do I actually need to subclass QStringListModel or can I use it as is? Looks like a tutorial may have lead me down a wrong path :)

Comment: If all you want is to set and access a `QStringList`, then you can use it as is--it a concrete subclass of `QAbstractItemModel`, that is, it contains no pure virtual functions.  I think Qt fully intends for users to use it as-is unless additional functionality/customization is genuinely needed.

Comment: Thanks @Matt Phillips,  I removed my custom subclass and use it directly. All is working great.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is at least one flaw in your approach: you hide the base class' function `QStringListModel::setStringList(const QStringList &)` with another one in your custom class. This is ok, if the function in the base class declared as virtual, but it is not. What you have to do, is just have another function, say `setMyStringList` that will call the base class function. For example:

```
void FileListModel::setMyStringList(QStringList newList)
{
    removeRows(0, this->rowCount());
    setStringList(newList); // Calls the base class function.
}
```

And I do not see a reason for keeping `fileNames` in your class. You can always get the string list by using `QStringListModel::stringList()` function.